# Dual boot system on SSD won't work after cloning with dd

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, ssd

I have a dual boot system (xubuntu, Windows 10) on a SSD with grub presenting me choices and booting into Linux unless I specify otherwise.

I tried to clone it to a larger SSD (connected via USB and an eternal housing for the process, later swapped it with the "old" one) using `sudo dd if=/dev/nvme01 of=/dev/sda bs=65536 status=progress`. The new SSD however is booting directly into Windows, giving me no chance to boot Linux, i.e. no boot menu is showing up.

In gparted, the partition tables of both disks look identical, resizing the ext4 partition to the full available space in the "new" SSD doesn't affect the outcome.

What went wrong, and how may I fix the problem?

Thanks for your assistance!

Edit: Pastebin link to the results from boot-info (working disk installed, /dev/nvme01, cloned disk at USB, /dev/sda).
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dRhd33mTys/

@oldfred: The other drive ("old" or "new") connected via USB doesn't affect the outcome. Also tried to assign a randomly generated UUID to the efi partition of the new drive, using gparted, with no effect.

@stumblebee: I tried with and without resizing the ext4 partition, using gparted, with no effect.

Comment: I always prefer new clean install & restore from backup. But lets see what is where. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair You cannot have both old & new drive connected when rebooting as duplicate UUIDs are not allowed.

Comment: `cpio` would be a better choice. `dd` duplicates your old SSD device to the new SSD device without consideration of a larger storage device.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It was a BIOS issue:

I selected the file grub64.efi in /EFI/ubuntu/ and then made sure it was the first item in the boot list.

Thanks for all comments!